# Grab data from an android/ios app via Script

Tags: android, python

I want to listen to data from a foreign app. I have already tried to find the Webervice via Wireshark, which provides the data. This one is encrypted. I come to a .aspx file with cryptic content.

An alternative would be to host an Android emulator on a server to somehow pull the information "off the screen".

What concrete possibilities exist here? A python script that looks at the emulator and intercepts and parses the data?

Comment: what is the legal reason to decrypt the website? stackoverflow is not a place to ask how to do a crime.

Comment: I dont want to decrypt it. The data is displayed normally via app. @AIMINPAN I am now looking for a way to parse something from the "display"